# Order of Approximation for a function

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, order-theory

I am attempting the following question:

assume $$ f(h) = p(h) + O(h^n)$$

and

$$ g(h) = q(h) + O(h^m) $$

as $$h \to 0$$

I am required to find the largest interger r such that

$$f(h) + g(h) = p(h) + q(h) + O(h^r)$$

I am bit confused but what i have done is consider the following :-

$$f(h) + g(h) = p(h) + O(h^n) +q(h) + O (h^m)$$

case where m > n then the following holds

$$f(h) + g(h) = p(h) + q(h) + O(h^m)$$ where m = r

case where m < n then the following holds

$$f(h) + g(h) = p(h) + q(h) + O(h^n)$$ where n = r

I am not sure if this is correct and how to go about evaluating this but i am hoping someone can guide me or correct me.

Comment: Why do you think the power in the order would be $m + n$ if $m = n$? I suggest you update your question instead of, or in addition to, commenting here.

Comment: r=min(m,n).  Seems fairly obvious.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yeah that makes sense if m = n then adding them makes no sense.

Comment: @herbsteinberg why cant r be the max of the two values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $h$ is going toward zero, small powers go to zero more slowly than large powers so they will dominate.  As an example, take $f(x)=x+x^2, g(x)=x+x^3, p(x)=q(x)=x$  Then $$f(x)=p(x)+O(x^2)\\
 g(x)=q(x)+O(x^3)\\
f(x)+g(x)=2x+x^2+x^3=p(x)+q(x)+x^2+x^3=p(x)+q(x)+O(x^2)$$
because as $x \to 0, x^2 + x^3 \in O(x^2)$ because the $x^3$ becomes negligible.
$$r=\min(m,n)$$

Comment: thank you for the explanation with the example greatly appreciated @ross millikan